# hamilton-connected graph characteristics

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to understand the answer to the following question:

[Prove a lower limit of $|E(G)|$ where for any $u,v\in G$, there exists a Hamilton path](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993518/prove-a-lower-limit-of-eg-where-for-any-u-v-in-g-there-exists-a-hamilto)

**Define a "Hamilton-connected graph G" as**

**For any vertices u,v∈G, a Hamilton path exists, where the two ends of the path are vertices u and v. Try to prove that if G is a Hamilton-connected graph and |V(G)|⩾4, the following inequation holds:
|E(G)|⩾[(3|V(G)|+1)/2]**

I don't the get the part he says "Since v has only two neighbors, then the first vertex in this Hamiltonian path must be v, or else v will be unreachable before reaching y. However, if the vertex v is second on the Hamiltonian path, then the only possible vertex to be third is y. But there must be at least 4 vertices so this is not a Hamiltonian path"

Why is not a Hamilton- connected?

P.D. I don't know if he means Hamiltonian or Hamilton as the definition of the problem (both are different).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to give as much details as possible :

Suppose that $G$ is hamilton-connected, i.e. for any pair of vertices $u$, $v$, there exists an Hamiltonian path from $u$ to $v$.

Suppose that in $G$, there exists a vertex $v$ of degree only 2, and call its neighbours $x$ and $y$.

If $G$ is hamiltonian, then it must exist an hamiltonian path from $x$ to $y$. In order to be hamiltonian, this path must include $v$ (as well as all other vertices of G, once only).

In the path $(x\ldots y$), suppose that $v$ is not in second position, i.e. the path is $(x\ldots av\ldots y)$. But then this means that $a$ is connected to $v$. $a$ can be only equal to $x$ or $y$ (the only neighbours of $v$). $a$ cannot by $y$ as an Hamiltonian path includes each vertex only once (and this one also ends by $y$). But $a$ cannot be $x$ too. This is a contradiction. Hence $v$ is in second position in the Hamiltonian path from $x$ to $y$. Therefore the path must be $(xv\ldots y)$.

But from $v$, the only vertex we can reach is $y$, therefore the path is exactly $(xvy)$

However we have $|V(G)|\geq 4$, therefore this path is not hamiltonian, (it would need to go throught every vertex in order to be hamiltonian). this is a contradiction.

Therefore there exist no hamiltonian path from $x$ to $y$, and then $G$ is not Hamilton-connected